# Which ReactJS lifecycle function should be used when an api needs to called more than once due to a prop change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-lifecycle

I have a parent component called `DeviceTab.js` and a child component called `Graph.js`. The child component receives two props: `name` and `span`. I need to make api calls in `Graph.js` that are dependent on the initial `name` or `span` props and when they get updated from the parent. Right now, I make the api call in `componentDidMount()` shown below. However when the props get updated (and the states that I have for these two props also get updated), the api doesn't get called. I think it's because `componentDidMount()` gets only called once. Should I use another lifecycle method and/or move the api call somewhere else?

In `Graph.js` I convert these two props to states as such:

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({ device: props.device })
    this.setState({ span: props.span })
  }
```

These two props are used as parameters in an api function call in `componentDidMount()` in my child component as such:

```js
componentDidMount(){
   const {name, span} = this.state
   fetch('https://devices-api.com/name=${name}&span=${span}')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error: ", error))
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ devices : data });
      });
}
```

When the parent props for `name` and `span` get *updated* in the *parent* component, I use `componentDidUpdate()` in the *child* component to update the child's *name* and *span* states as such:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.name !== prevProps.name) {
       this.setState({
        name: this.props.name,
       });
    }
    if (this.props.span !== prevProps.span) {
      this.setState({
       span: this.props.span,
      });
   }
  }
```

**EDIT**:
I took @ Harmandeep Singh Kalsi 's advice and move the api call into `componentDidUpdate` but am still having issues with loading my data. Here's the updated method:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){ 
    if (this.props.name !== prevProps.name) {
       this.setState({ name: this.props.name})
       // your api call goes here
       const {name, span} = this.state
       fetch('https://devices-api.com/name=${name}&span=${span}')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .catch((error) => console.error("Error: ", error))
         .then((data) => {
         this.setState({ devices : data });
        });
       }
    }
    if (this.props.span !== prevProps.span) {
       this.setState({ span: this.props.span})
       // your api call goes here
       const {name, span} = this.state
       fetch('https://devices-api.com/name=${name}&span=${span}')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .catch((error) => console.error("Error: ", error))
         .then((data) => {
         this.setState({ devices : data });
        });
       }
    }
}
```

When I `console.log` the api url, I am seeing an infinite # of calls using the initial prop values passed from the parent i.e. `https://devices-api.com/name=test1&span=2`. When updated prop values are passed from the parent, there is another set of infinite api calls with the updated values i.e. `https://devices-api.com/name=test2&span=4` . This prevents my component which uses the data from the api response from loading. My render method is as such:

```js
if (this.state.devices.length > 0) {
      return (
        <Bar
          data={this.state.devices}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="sweet-loading">
          <HashLoader css={override} size={150} color={"#42a315"} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

I just see nonstop Hashloader and half rendered graph switching back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting the api calls in the conditional in `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)`. This issue was with the conditionals. I had to check the types for `this.props.name` vs `prevProps.name`. I used `shallow-equal` to check as such:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if (!shallowEqualObjects(prevProps.name, this.props.name)) {
     // api call here
  }
}
```

For reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shallow-equal

Answer (score 2):

You should use **componentDidUpdate** instead   For details check this link : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){ 
   if(currentProps !== previProps){
     <your api call goes here>
   }
}
```

Comment: I moved the api call into `componentDidUpdate()` as you described. However in my api call, I use `setState()` to set my response data as a state. Although I am able to make an api call with the updated props that were passed from the parent, this is causing an infinite re-rendering of the child component and the api is called many times. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Could you please add the code , how you did that ? Without seeing code it is difficult to answer . If possible can you provide the link to sandbox with the code?

Comment: Sorry about the vague response I updated the original post with what I did. Thanks for your time Harmandeep!

Comment: The API call is happening , even if the props change or not . It is not wrapped in the if where you are comparing the prevProps to current props. Please read the documentation again https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Apologies, I updated my code where the api call is wrapped in both the conditionals. Original post is updated. Same thing still happening.

Comment: Can you add the code in sandbox and share the link here?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-shadow-vu1r4 I put the general structure of both parent and child components here. I am unable to provide the exact api and thus the responses from the api's are empty. Not sure if it's possible to identify if it's a structural/logical error. The issue is that when the device dropdown and span dropdown is selected, there is an infinite api call with the updated values in Child.js. And the graph is unable to render properly. Many thanks!